# SSL connection working with OpenSSL but not with NSS

Tags: php, curl, openssl, nss

I'm trying to connect to a website using curl. On my local machine i can connect, but on the development server it doesn't work.

```
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true );
```

On my local machine curl is configured to use OpenSSL and on the development machine curl is using NSS.

Here's the output i get on the **development machine**

```
    * About to connect() to www.zomato.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 104.81.108.141...
* Connected to www.zomato.com (104.81.108.141) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.zomato.com,OU=Engineering,O=Zomato Media Private Limited,L=New Delhi,ST=Delhi,C=IN
*       start date: May 04 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*       expire date: Aug 03 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*       common name: *.zomato.com
*       issuer: CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US
> GET /sk/slovakia HTTP/1.1
Host: www.zomato.com
Accept-Language: en,ro;q=0.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

* Operation timed out after 3000 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
```

And here's the output i get on the **local machine**

```
    *   Trying 104.84.165.29...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.zomato.com (104.84.165.29) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: G:\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=IN; ST=Delhi; L=New Delhi; O=Zomato Media Private Limited; OU=Engineering; CN=*.zomato.com
*  start date: May  4 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  3 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.zomato.com" matched cert's "*.zomato.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /sk/slovakia HTTP/1.1
Host: www.zomato.com
Accept-Language: en,ro;q=0.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: The first output is clearly telling you that it timed out ... 3 seconds is not a lot.

Comment: @your_average_programmer Trying changing curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3 ); to curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 ); and let us know what happens.

Comment: It's the same result. On the local machine the response is received in under a second